# Improve conversion speed of list of tuples to dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list `l` consisting of tuples of length 5. The first four entries are strings, the last one is an integer.
A dummy function to create such a list may look as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import uuid
def get_dummy_data(n=10000):
    l = []
    for i in range(n):
        name = np.random.choice(["Cat", "Dog", "Duck"], 1)[0]
        c_id = uuid.uuid4().hex
        t_id = uuid.uuid4().hex
        l.append((c_id, t_id, name, "canFly", 1))
        if np.random.random() < 0.8:
            l.append((c_id, t_id, name, "isHungry", 0))
    return l
```

Now this list `l` contains tuples which have identical first three elements but differ in the last two. This is exemplified here by appending the same tuple again with 80% chance but changing the last two elements.

The goal is to convert this list of length-5 tuples into a dictionary in which the key is the first entry of the tuple (c_id) and the value is structured like this (t_id, (name, {"isHungry":0})) or this: (t_id, (name, {"canFly":1, "isHungry":0})).

This can be achieved by the following loop:

```
res = {}
for y in l:
    if y[0] not in res:
        res[y[0]] = (y[1], (y[2], {y[3]: y[4]}))
    else:
        res[y[0]][1][1].update({y[3]: y[4]})
```

The question is now: can I make this faster? There might be more than two tuples in the list `l` with the same `c_id` (in contrast to the get_dummy_data function) and we cannot assume any order in `l`.
I always have a bad feeling when doing an explicit for loop to fill a dict so I bet there is a good way to make this faster.

Comment: "I always have a bad feeling when doing an explicit for loop to fill a dict " as opposed to...? Anyway, is there actually a performance issue you are running in to? This is running pretty much instantaneously, faster than the `get_dummy_data` function.

Comment: Without more information on either your goal and context, or on your context. It's hard to optimize anything more than what was provided by juanpa

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga In this particular case I was just wondering if there is a faster solution than mine. So lets call it "academic interest"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do basic micro-optimizations that also make your code more readable. A big one is not using `some_dict.update({x:y})` instead of `some_dict[x] = y`. But here's some timing differences:

```
In [12]: %%timeit
    ...: res = {}
    ...: for y in data:
    ...:     if y[0] not in res:
    ...:         res[y[0]] = (y[1], (y[2], {y[3]: y[4]}))
    ...:     else:
    ...:         res[y[0]][1][1].update({y[3]: y[4]})
    ...:
100 loops, best of 3: 15.3 ms per loop

In [13]: %%timeit
    ...: res = {}
    ...: for a,b,c,d,e in data:
    ...:     if a not in res:
    ...:         res[a] = (b, (c, {d: e}))
    ...:     else:
    ...:         res[a][1][1][d] = e
    ...:
100 loops, best of 3: 11 ms per loop
```

Here it is with `.update`. Note, each `y[...]` is a method-call, which slows things down. But the biggest component of the time savings was avoiding the `.update({...}`. Note, that approach requires the creation of a whole `dict` object for no good reason:

```
In [18]: %%timeit
    ...: res = {}
    ...: for a,b,c,d,e in data:
    ...:     if a not in res:
    ...:         res[a] = (b, (c, {d: e}))
    ...:     else:
    ...:         res[a][1][1].update({d:e})
    ...:
100 loops, best of 3: 13.8 ms per loop
```

Comment: micro optimization is better than _no_ optimization.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre the biggest issue for me here is readability.

Comment: I like that you explained *why* this runs faster!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga check my update; I borrowed the unpacking & dict updating from your answer and my solution is 20% faster than yours now :)

Answer (score 1):

this kind of loop is generally slow:

```
res = {}
for y in l:
    if y[0] not in res:
        res[y[0]] = (y[1], (y[2], {y[3]: y[4]}))
    else:
        res[y[0]][1][1].update({y[3]: y[4]})
```

because you're testing if the key belongs to the dictionary twice and there's the `if/else` statement.

I would use the binding property of variables in `lambda` & unpacking (borrowed from juanpa answer):

```
import collections
res = collections.defaultdict(lambda : (b, (c, {d: e})))

for a,b,c,d,e in l:
    res[a][1][1][d] = e
```

if key isn't in dictionary `defaultdict` creates a key using the current value of `a`, `b` ..., (thanks to `lambda` evaluating the values when executing, not when declaring) saving the test and creating the proper key each time. Now the `update` part is a bit redundant but it still should be faster because there's no `if/then` test.

This solution is faster than juanpa (already good) answer on my machine (0.23 seconds vs 0.27 seconds). I would call that a good collaborating effort since my first version was slower.

Comment: Actually, I'm getting *slower* on my tests. The biggest time sink here from fiddling around with it is the unnecessary dict-initialization. But that's a clever, albeit cheeky use of closures.

Comment: On my machine, the version with the defaultdict runs slightly slower than my attempt.

Comment: edited: mixing juanpa good ideas with closure default dict hack my answer is even faster.

Comment: Even after your edit, this does not seem to be faster than @juanpa.arrivillaga's version.

Comment: surprising, not the case on my machine. You don't want to use `time` on the `import collections` though...

Comment: Sure, but repeating my measurements over and over again, I cannot see a speed increase with your solution. We need a tie breaker ;)

Comment: sure :) maybe it depends on the python version. Let's see.